# Inheritance of file descriptors - Python 3.4

Tags: python, sockets, file-descriptor

The documentation under https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#fd-inheritance about "Inheritance of file descriptors" says:

"On UNIX, non-inheritable file descriptors are closed in child processes at the execution of a new program, other file descriptors are inherited."

Also the documentation to the sockets says that, "the newly created socket is non-inheritable."

I have just tested it with following code:

```
import socket, os

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('localhost', 9999))
sock.listen(512)
sock.settimeout(1)

print("Socket inheritable?: {}".format(sock.get_inheritable()))

pid = os.fork()
if not pid: # child process
    print(sock)
else:
    pass
```

By calling "sock.get_inheritable()" I get False, that means the socket is not inheritable.
But the child process seems to have inherited the socket descriptor.

Am I missing something?
Why is that so?

Thanks

Update:

Here is the "server.py" waiting on the accept in the child process:

```
import socket, os, time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('localhost', 9999))
sock.listen(512)
sock.setblocking(True)

print("Socket inheritable?: {}".format(sock.get_inheritable()))

pid = os.fork()
if not pid: # child process
    sock, addr = sock.accept()
    data = sock.recv(100)
    print(data.decode())
else:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

"client.py" sends "Hello" to the socket:

```
import socket, time, select, sys

msg = "Hello".encode()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost',9999))
s.setblocking(1)
s.send(msg)
s.close()
```

After starting the server.py and running the "client.py" I see "Hello" message printed in the terminal of "server.py".

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this, but I think the inheritance only applies "at the execution of a new program", meaning child processes created with `os.fork` will inherit the file descriptors, but those created with `os.system`, `subprocess`, etc, will not inherit file descriptors.

Answer (score -1):

Non-inheritable means that the descriptor is closed, as it says in your quote. It does not mean the reference to the socket object in Python disappears.

The more meaningful test would be to try and read from the socket in both branches of the conditional.

Comment: What is the point of closing the fd? Is the socket object still usable in child process?

Comment: That's the point -- the socket object is not usable in the child process, only the parent.

Comment: Just tested it, I can perfectly receive data on the socket in the child process.

Comment: @user2624744, if you'd like, you can post your updated code showing the new test in your question.